# I submitted 2 DS-160 applications to 2 different US embassies. Can this be a problem?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, applications

Background: 
I am a PhD student. I intend to attend a scientific conference in the US in August, where I'll be presenting a paper. I recently submitted a completed DS-160 application form to the US Embassy in London for a B-2 visa (online). However, when I tried to book an appointment for visa interview, I saw that the earliest date was too close to a planned trip to Spain (I'll travel to Spain soon, will be there for a few months). I decided not to book the appointment with the US Embassy in London. I completed another DS-160 application which I submitted online to the US Embassy in Madrid, Spain. I have also scheduled an appointment with them (US Embassy in Madrid), and have received an appointment confirmation.

It appears I can only "Print Confirmation" and "Email Confirmation" when I login to the DS-160 application form (the one I submitted to the US Embassy in London). There is no option to delete the application :(

Question: 
Is there a way to cancel/delete the DS-160 application I submitted to the US Embassy in London (online submission)? Will such a cancellation be considered a visa refusal/withdrawal? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Follow-up: I got a B1/B2 visa without any problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't 'Submitted' your DS-160 to the consulate.  Fundamentally, you submit it to the consulate when you appear there for your interview (technically now days you generally just submit a reference page, but they don't consider it as being submitted until that point).

So no, you will have no issues with what you've done, and there is no need to delete the original application for London.  The original DS-160 you filled will never be acted upon, and will probably eventually be silently deleted.